# WMS layer not displaying in Leaflet Time Dimension

Tags: leaflet, wms, openlayers-2, timeslider

I have a postgis table which is uploaded in Geoserver as WMS. The table is of a road ,has timestamp and contains around 250 records at 5min interval. It looks like this in openlayers

[image]

Now i want to visualize these with the help of a time slider plugin given at http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example1.html.

The code is as shown below

```
var map = L.map('map', {
fullscreenControl: true,
timeDimension: true,
timeDimensionControl: true,
zoom: 12,
center: [30.30, 78.05]
});

var m_wms ="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mayur/wms";
var roads = L.tileLayer.wms(m_wms, {
layers: 'test3',
format: 'image/png',
transparent: true,
colorscalerange: '-0.4,0.4',
abovemaxcolor: "extend",
belowmincolor: "extend",
numcolorbands: 100,    
styles: 'boxfill/rainbow'
});


var proxy = 'server/proxy.php';
var road_time = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(roads, {
proxy: proxy,
updateTimeDimension: true,
});


var overlayMaps = {
"Road Traffic Information": road_time
};


var baseLayers = getCommonBaseLayers(map); // see baselayers.js
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

road_time.addTo(map);
```

As it can be seen below that time in time slider is updated with the time in the wms link. But i cannot see the layer.
The output is as shown [image]

I have checked and the projection is also correct, but somehow i cannot see the layer in the map.

All suggestions are welcome

Comment: Check the GetMap request that the client is sending for GeoServer and add it to your question. It can also depend on the rendering styles. Your linestring may become just a single point with the time dimension.

Comment: The first image is of getmap request only, If i follow this example my layer is shown on the map  http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wmst.html but when using leaflet it is not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have done this now, the problem was with the wms defination, the styles specified was for the polygon layer but i was using lines, Below is the modified code and it works fine.
As i change the time the color of the road changes.

```
var roads = L.tileLayer.wms(m_wms, {
layers: 'test3',
format: 'image/png',
transparent: true,
});
```

[image]
[image]